# how to get imei number in phonegap app with imeiplugin

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins, imei

Can anyone explain to me how to get the device's IMEI number from Phonegap?
I am using the IMEI plugin in my app it is not showing anything.

To install, I have tried both:

```
phonegap plugin add https://github.com/zho/phonegap-imeiplugin.git
```

-- OR --

```
cordova plugin add imeiplugin
```

Example Usage:

```
window.plugins.imeiplugin.getImei(callback);

function callback(imei) {
    console.log("My Android IMEI :" + imei);
```

I want the output to be displayed when user opens the app, but it is not showing.

Comment: every thing is clear in that link right....so whats the issue you are  facing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**here is the solution that how can you  use imeiplugin**
   Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
   <body>
     <h1 id="demo"></h1>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script> app.initialize(); </script>
   </body>
 </html>
```

**Index.js**

```
var app = {
        // Application Constructor
        initialize: function () {
            app.bindEvents();
        },
        bindEvents: function () {
            document.addEventListener('deviceready', app.onDeviceReady, false);
        },
        onDeviceReady: function () {
            window.plugins.imeiplugin.getImei(callback);    
        }
    };
    function callback(imei) {
        var element=document.getElementById("demo");
        element.value=imei;

    }
```

Comment: I am still not getting imei number, It is showing blank

Comment: how to output the result to div in html

Comment: Please review my answer again .

Comment: Your Welcome But please keep helping people according to your skill set

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with the plugin you provided it showing an error like imeiplugin is unefined  at window.plugins.imeiplugin.getImei(callback);

so i tried with the below and its worked for me

```
cordova plugin add org.hygieiasoft.cordova.uid
```

and call the finction on device ready

```
 document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {
        console.log(cordova.plugins.uid.IMEI);
    }
```

[check this](https://github.com/hygieiasoft/cordova-plugin-uid) for more info

Comment: plugin is not even installing

Comment: Have u tried with Installing from git hub repo??what is the issue while installing

Comment: The error I am getting is registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/org.hygieiasoft.cordova.uid

Comment: may i know how your trying to install

Comment: try this to install the plugin  cordova plugin add https://github.com/hygieiasoft/cordova-plugin-uid.git

Comment: can we go for team viewer ??

Comment: At what time can you connet in team viewer

Comment: what about after 8.30 pm today IST?

Comment: hi i am available now

Comment: sorry, i was not their, are you available today after 10.00 pm.